# Making background curvature variable in QFT on curved spacetime

Tags: quantum-gravity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, klein-gordon-equation, qft-in-curved-spacetime

In QFT on curved spacetime one may start with a Klein-Gordon like equation
$$(\square_g - m^2 j) \phi = j,$$
where $\square_g := g^{\mu \nu} \nabla_\mu \nabla_\mu$ is the D'Alembertian operator, and $j$ some current, and $\phi,j$ are operator valued 'functions' (possibly distributions).

Can one add the operator Einstein equation
$$R_{\mu \nu} - 2^{-1} R g_{\mu \nu} = C \cdot T(\phi),$$
where $T(\phi)$ is the energy momentum stress tensor of $\phi$, and $R$ and $g$ are regarded as operators, as well
as the coefficents $g$ implicitely appearing in the covariant derivative $\nabla$ appearing in $\square_g$,
and so obtaining a QFT of Klein-Gordon equation and gravity?

Clearly many questions and further details are open. Maybe here the Einstein equation is not renormalizible, but $\phi$ might still be.

---

(((
Obsolete:

Can one make curvature tensor $g$ variable, and quantum, in this picture by giving feedback to it from the, presumably quantum, energy-momentum stress tensor of $\phi$ via the Einstein equation?

In other words, adding  some equation  like
$$g = g_0 + g(FunctionOfEinsteinequation(StressMomentumTensor(\phi))$$

EDIT:

To be more specific:

Can one quantize Einstein equation for $g$ (turning to operator) and add it to the above Klein-Gordon equation, that is,  the equation (short form for the standard equation)
$$EinsteinEquation(g,StressTensor(\phi))= 0$$
and compute $\phi$, but possibly not compute $g$ due to non-renormalizibilty.

)))

Comment: You cant do this.Einstein's field equations are NOT linear.

Comment: You may write $EinsteinEquation(g, StressTensor(\phi) + S_0)=0$ if this is your concern.

Comment: what is $g_{0}$?.

Comment: Some given background metric.

Comment: Like the Minkowski metric?Your approach will work at regions with small gravity.

Comment: No, actually a very strong metric.

Comment: “curvature tensor $g$” $g$ is called the metric tensor, not the curvature tensor. “Curvature tensor” means [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are asking (question needs some better formatting), but I think what you are asking is "*can you write the metric so that it receives corrections from the QFT?*" I presume your $g_{0}$ is the background metric of some sort. If this is what you are asking, then the answer is that this is the perturbative description of semiclassical gravity, where you have a background metric $g_{\mu \nu }=\delta _{\mu \nu }+\epsilon h_{\mu \nu }$ (for some small $\epsilon $) satisfying the semiclassical field equations $G_{\mu \nu }=\langle T_{\mu \nu }\rangle $ and you consider terms that go like $\epsilon h_{\mu \nu }$ at linear order and so on. (Usually higher order terms are dropped, as apparent from the small values of $\epsilon $.) If you are working in, say, gravity coupled to a scalar QFT, then you get something like what you are asking. Again; not sure what you are asking, or what you mean by "$g$ being a function of the field equations being a function of the stress tensor being a function of the field", but this is what I think you are asking.

Comment: Yes, this it was I am asking, if $h_{\mu v_\mu}$ is the correction from the field $\phi$.Yes, $g_0$ is background. Ultimatively, I ask if I can drop $g_0$ completely, and do quantum gravity completely in this vein. (Theoretically, not computable in terms of perturbation.)

Comment: Background metric should however be $g_{\mu \nu} = (g_0)_{mu \nu} + \epsilon h_{\mu \nu}$ (not flat plus correction), and be quantum like.

Comment: Not $Gμν=⟨Tμν⟩ $ but $Gμν=Tμν$ (quantum). The metric should then be quantum numbers. Which say, are then multiplied as operators with operators $\phi$ in the Klein_gordon like equation.

Comment: @hansel I am not sure I follow. What I wrote is better written as $g=g^{(0)}+g^{(1)}+g^{(2)}+\dots $, where the indices are orders. (1) What do you mean by "... drop $g_{0}$ completely and do quantum gravity... "? (2) What do you mean by "... be quantum like"? These corrections are because you are in a gravity+QFT case, where you have quantized dynamics around a background spacetime fixed by $\delta $ above. The same applies to (3) your statement about "... not $\langle T_{\mu \nu }\rangle $ but $T_{\mu \nu }$ (quantum) ..."; $\langle T_{\mu \nu }\rangle $ is the vev of the stress tensor.

Comment: I have added an edit to above post.

Comment: (1) Set $g_0 = 0$. (2) to be operators, not numbers. (3) Yes, not numbers  $⟨Tμν⟩$ but operators $Tμν$

Comment: @hansel Can you edit just once again asking what your question is? It is still not clear. What do you mean by "set $g^{(0)}=0$"? Suppose we were in the Schwarzschild black hole case. Why wouldn't you want to compute corrections to $g^{(0)}$? Or in the case of strong cosmic censorship, large backreactions to this are what cause the inner Cauchy horizon to be instable in perturbative semiclassical gravity. Kindly update the question making it just a little more clear.

Comment: @hansel What is $C$ in your edit?

Comment: $C= - 8 \pi G c^{-4}$

Comment: @hansel Well, firstly the negative sign is somewhat troublesome when you would deal with computations involving say the trace of $T_{\mu \nu }$. The stress-tensor is a function of matter fields $\Phi _{1}\dots \Phi _{n}$, so it is redundant to mention $T_{\mu \nu }[\Phi ]$. Now, coming to the point of the question, how would you compute $\Phi $? Are you asking if $g$ and $\Phi $ can both be "quantum" in the sense that we do not start by assuming a Lagrangian with a metric $g$ with some fixed $\delta $?